# Circle progress bar keeps looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, each

I have a circle progress script found here: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Circular-Progress-Bar-with-jQuery-Canvas-Circle-Progress/

I added it to my website, the thing is that I have these element around the middle of the page (not in view when page loads). My intention is to show the animation once the user scrolls down to that position, however the effect keeps looping on every scroll. How can I make it to run only once when the element gets on view and prevent for looping and/or restart?

Here's my code so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/1f58u1o5/1/

CSS

```
.progressbar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 25px;
}

.circle {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.circle canvas { vertical-align: middle; }

.circle div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.circle strong i {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.circle span {
    display: block;
    color: #aaa;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
<h3>Sed scelerisque</h3>
<div class="progressbar">
    <div class="circle" data-percent="98"><div></div><p>Quisque's</p></div>
</div>
<div class="progressbar">
    <div class="circle" data-percent="30"><div></div><p>Maecenas</p></div>
</div>
<div class="progressbar">
    <div class="circle" data-percent="77"><div></div><p>Pellentesque</p></div>
</div>
<div class="progressbar">
    <div class="circle" data-percent="49"><div></div><p>Etiam sodales</p></div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    function animateElements(){
        $('.progressbar').each(function(){
            var elementPos  = $(this).offset().top;
            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            var percent     = $(this).find('.circle').attr('data-percent');
            var percentage  = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
            if(elementPos<topOfWindow+$(window).height()-30){
                $(this).find('.circle').circleProgress({
                    startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
                    value: percentage,
                    thickness: 14,
                    fill: { color: '#1B58B8' }
                }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event,progress,stepValue) {
                    $(this).find('div').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(2) + '%');
                }).stop();
            }
        });
    }

    // Show animated elements
    animateElements();
    $(window).scroll(animateElements);
});
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edward_lee/1f58u1o5/2/

Add data attribute on `<div class="progressbar">` to check the animation is played or not. Its initial value is `false` because the animation is not played yet.

`<div class="progressbar" data-animate="false">`

Add the attribute is false condition on if statement `if(elementPos<topOfWindow+$(window).height()-30 && !animate)`.

Once the animation is played, set the attribute to `true`.

```
$('.progressbar').each(function(){
    var elementPos  = $(this).offset().top;
    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    var percent     = $(this).find('.circle').attr('data-percent');
    var percentage  = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
    var animate = $(this).data('animate');
    if(elementPos<topOfWindow+$(window).height()-30 && !animate){
        $(this).data('animate', true);
        $(this).find('.circle').circleProgress({
            startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
            value: percentage,
            thickness: 14,
            fill: { color: '#1B58B8' }
        }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event,progress,stepValue) {
            $(this).find('div').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(2) + '%');
        }).stop();
    }
});
```